# Android where to put scroll when I want to add element programmatically

Tags: android

i want to build a screen for user to get his marks on competitions, the screen will have may row, each row for one competition, where have i to put scroll in my layout and how ?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >





        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:weightSum="2" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMarksCompetitionID"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Competition"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMarksMarks"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Marks"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMarksQuestionsNum"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Questions"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and please would you give me a nice layout for that three textviews :) i am new to android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate **TableLayout** inside **ScrollView** to make your layout scrollable